# how to upload a file at server?

Tags: jsp

I want to upload a pdf from client side to server.
I hav use following code..

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%

String contentType = request.getContentType();

if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0))     {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());

    int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
    byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
    int byteRead = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) 
    {
        byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
        totalBytesRead += byteRead;
    }

    String file = new String(dataBytes);

    String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
    int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
    String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex +1,contentType.length());
    int pos;

    pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
    int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
    int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation))
    .getBytes()).length;
    saveFile="http://hpws1/shared_mxd/pdf/" + saveFile;

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();

    %><Br><table border="2"><tr><td><b>You have successfully
```

upload the file by the name of:
        <% out.println(saveFile); %> <%
        }
        %>

where "saveFile="http://hpws1/shared_mxd/pdf/" + saveFile; " is the path of server.
but this path is not recognized by the browser and gave error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".
How can i resolve dis???

Comment: where you want to save the file  ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use a form to send the file? Like this:

```
<FORM ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'
 method='POST' action='/myservlet'>
<INPUT TYPE='file' NAME='mptest'>
<INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='upload'>
</FORM>
```

Comment: ofcourse i hav use a form like u hav shown. And it is working correctly.The problem is: The above code works for me if i save a file at the local system itself but if i want to save it at server location " http://hpws1/shared_mxd/pdf/ " it is not working..